# What's does error handling option of replace mean in str.decode/encode?

Tags: string, python-2.7

The Python documentation on [str.decode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode) and encode allow an "error handling scheme".  What does the `replace` option mean or do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the link in the doc you referenced, it goes here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codec-base-classes

Which says `replace` does this:

> Replace with a suitable replacement character; Python will use the official U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER for the built-in Unicode codecs on decoding and ‘?’ on encoding.

[U+FFFD](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm) is:

> Used to replace an incoming character whose value is unknown or unrepresentable in Unicode.

So basically the `replace` option puts a "dummy" character in the output wherever the input had a "bad" character that could not be decoded or encoded.